# Could not open/read USGS raster file

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, envi, erdas-imagine

I could not open/read the following .img file.

The document below says it is a raster file.

http://edc2.usgs.gov/1KM/land_sea_mask.php

I tried to open it using many ways such as Q-Gis software, and Gdal translate, but could not.

Gdal translate reports error that unrecognized file..

That strange file is here:

http://edcftp.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/avhrr/mask/wvsdn_mask_world.img.gz (3.54 MB).
I extracted it using winrar and the extracted file is 662 MB.I tried to open the extracted one.

Is someone familiar with this file?

Comment: *.img suggests that it is in ERDAS IMAGINE format.

Comment: @PolyGeo gdal translate would have to convert it, right?

Comment: This suggests so http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hfa.html - but its not an area I claim any skills in so I'll defer to others on this one.

Comment: @PolyGeo Since you are an ArcGIS specialist: can that open the file?

Comment: @AndreJ I just tried using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and it gave an error: `Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL does not recognize the file as ERDAS imagine, as promised by the extension `.img`. But it looks only at the file extension, and does no further investigation on the content of the file.

---

**EDIT**

Comparing with other data from the [site](http://edc2.usgs.gov/1KM/goodesarticle.php), they seem to provide unformatted raw binary.
The mask should be 17347 lines by 40031 samples (columns)

So I created an ESRI hdr file for it with this content:

```
BYTEORDER      I
LAYOUT         BIL
NROWS          17347
NCOLS          40031
NBANDS         1
NBITS          8
BANDROWBYTES   17347
TOTALROWBYTES  17347
PIXELTYPE      SIGNEDINT
ULXMAP         -20015000.
ULYMAP         8673000.
XDIM           1000
YDIM           1000
NODATA         -32768
```

(actually I took a SRTM file, exported it as hdr and changed the size definitions)

Renamed the .img to .bil, and created a .prj file for the used Goode Homolosine:

```
PROJCS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",GEOGCS["GCS_Normal Sphere (r=6370997)",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["sphere",6370997,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

And got an image that fits quite good to Natural Earths vector data in green:
[image]